# Overriding the Hashcode func for Sliding Puzzle problem

Tags: java, hashcode

I am assigning each state of a sliding puzzle a hashcode. The code I currently have is returning the same hashcode for different states. Does anyone know an efficient way to uniquely hash states of a sliding puzzle?

```
public int hashCode() {
    int total = 2;


    if(board[0][0] == -1) {
        total += 9;
    }
    else{
        total += 9 * board[0][0];
    }

    if(board[0][1] == 1){
        total += 1;
    }
    else{
        total += 1 * board[0][1];
    }

    if(board[0][2] == 2){
        total += 2;
    }
    else{
        total += 2 * board[0][2];
    }

    if(board[1][0] == 3){
        total += 3;
    }
    else{
        total += 3 * board[1][0];
    }

    if(board[1][1] == 4){
        total += 4;
    }
    else{
        total += 4 * board[1][1];
    }
```

..etc

Comment: I cut out the rest of the code to submit this post but it runs the same logic up

Comment: How many slots are there and how many different states are possible? It's quite possible that the number of combinations exceeds 2^32, which would mean you can't do a perfect hash in `int hashCode()`. Which is not usually an issue, as dratenik points out below.

Comment: The code in the question suggests a 3x3 board, which could also be uniquely encoded by the less ambitious method of using the content of the fields as decimal digits read in sequence. This would still fit into a 32-bit int (max. result 876543210).

Answer (score 4):

Hash codes can be non-unique. Hash collisions are a fact of life that implementations should be able to deal with.

What you are looking for is more of a representation of the state. A state of this puzzle is a permutation of the numbers 0 (? meaning empty), 1-8. So you're looking for a unique numeric representation of a permutation.

This would be called a Lehmer code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Numbering_permutations

So much for theory but how do you implement that? Here is a suggested algorithm:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Lehmer-code-A-complete-translation-from-permutation-to-decimal-by-way-of-the_fig1_230831447

Answer (score 0):

Calculating a hash code for an array is a common task the Java API provides a method for:

```
Arrays.deepHashCode(board)
```

(If you have additional knowledge about the content of the array you may be able to craft a better hashcode function, but the generic one is quite decent, and your time may be better spent optimizing elsewhere)

If you're curious how the Java API does this, here is the salient part of the implementation:

```
public static int hashCode(int a[]) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 1;
    for (int element : a)
        result = 31 * result + element;

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, the implementation multiplies the previous result with a constant before adding the next element. If we imagine the result stored in a [positional number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) with base 31, this shifts the digits of the previous result one position to the left, before adding information about the new element in the lowest digit. Because the previous digits have been moved out of the way, the is no overlap between the old and new digits, and the information can be reconstructed perfectly as long as the result does not overflow. And even if the result does overflow, it will be reduced by power of 2, and since 31 is coprime to 2, some information about the old digits will remain.

If you know that your array contains small numbers (for instance, less than 15), multiplying by 15 rather than 31 would be preferable, as it can encode more elements before starting to overflow, resulting in slightly better spread hash values.